# Azure blob access from Html web app

Tags: html, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a html Web App running off of Azure. I'm trying to figure out how to write and read to a blob from there. I understand I will need a Shared access key, connection string, use a HTTPS and/or HTTP request, use CORS, but now I'm just trying to fill in some blanks about how to set up the endpoints and if I need something in the back end of the web app. How can implement setting up the endpoints with the CORS?  Do I need to set up a logic app? What else do I need to set up with the Web App? Will it be better to set up on a Virtual machine?  Thank you in advance.

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several web apps tutorials used with blob storage. Some tutorials i'd highly recommend are as below:

**[Gallery Photo Web App tutorial:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-webapp/)**
Provides an example with sample code on how to use a web application with Azure blob storage

**[Using Azure storage with hosted Azure Web App:](http://www.sharecareinspire.com/azure-storage-part-3-read-and-edit-blob-storage-data-from-azure-web-app/)**
Provides an example on how to integrate and use storage with Azure hosted Web app, including the source code.

**[Video tutorial:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZA7onkSk9c)**
Video Tutorial showing the use of Azure web App and Storage operations.

These should get you started.